# Undeclared identifier and type 'int' unexpected error when calling a class from main

Tags: c++, templates, hash

Hey guys so I am working on a Hash program in C++ for my class.  I am using a template T class for my header file and when I try to call the class constructor from main it gives me a undeclared identifier and type 'int' unexpected error.  Here is my HashTable.h file:

```
#pragma once
#include "Record.h"
#define MAXHASH 1000
#ifndef HASHTABLE_H
#define HASHTABLE_H
using namespace std;

template <class T> class HashTable
{
public:
    HashTable();
    ~HashTable();
    bool insert(int, T, int&);
    bool remove(int);
    bool find(int, T&);
    float alpha();
private:
    int key;
    T value;
 };

#endif
```

and here is my main:

```
#include "HashTable.h"
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    HashTable<int> *test = new HashTable<int>();
    return 0;
}
```

Here's the constructor in the .cpp file as well:

```
#pragma once
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "HashTable.h"
#include "Record.h"
#define HASHTABLE_CPP
#ifndef HASTABLE_CPP


template <class T>
HashTable<T>::HashTable()
{
    Record hashArray = new Record[MAXHASH];
    for (int i = 0; i < MAXHASH; i++)
    {
        hashArray[i]->key = 0;
        hashArray[i]->value = NULL;
    }
}
```

The specific errors I am getting are:

> ```
> Error C2062   type 'int' unexpected identifier 
>
> Error C2065   'HashTable': undeclared identifier
> ```

Both the errors point to the call line in main.

It is difficult because I can't test my program until I can get this test hash to work.  Any input on how to fix this issue would be awesome!

Comment: use `typename T`

Comment: Not a dupe of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file) yet but you will run into it once you get it to compile.

Comment: Off topic regarding: `HashTable<int> *test = new HashTable<int>();` Don't new unless you have to. `HashTable<int> test;` will most likely do what you want. Also watch out for `Record hashArray = new Record[MAXHASH];` `hashArray ` is a local variable, so you will lose track of where the allocated storage is once the function exits. Consider making it a member variable and, as before, avoid `new`ing it.

Comment: The first thing to do when you get mysterious compile-time errors with Visual Studio is to remove `#include "stdafx.h"`; it's a Microsoft thing, and it's supposed to be just a compile-time optimization, but it often screws things up. (Also, it should be the **first** `#include` directive if you use it)

Comment: I feel pretty stupid but it was because the #include "stdafx.h" was not first. haha Thanks so much guys!

Answer (score 0):

the old Microsoft application file extensions interface "stdafx.h" has to be the first directive listed if the pre-compiled header is used.  It actually works best because VS expects it...I always use it.